# vb.net fit multiple control form when resize

Tags: .net, vb.net

this is my code

```
Private Sub maind_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        dataview1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Right
        dataview2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Right
End Sub
```

when form get resize both control is Overlapping

[image]

i want like this
[image]

Comment: Use a TableLayoutPanel with two proportional Columns and anchor that.

Comment: Or set the form's MinimumSize property to ensure it stays usable.

Comment: thank you everyone now i use TableLayoutPanel andI it works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use TableLayoutPanel
2. put your control in TableLayoutPanel
3. set your contorl dock = fill

it works perfectly

Comment: For more specific info, see [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?630636).